# Удаленное включение серверов

Tags: сервер

В общем, поскольку начались периодические отключения питания, возникла необходимость включения серверов из дома. Как можно реализовать данное чудо? wake on lan не подходит.

Comment: Ну я бы сделал так. Один комп запитал бы от аккумуляторов, к нему бы через плату pci подвел бы несколько реле и управлял бы этими реле по сети.

Comment: есть розетки, управляемые по сети или usb

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос стоит в том, чтобы сервера поднимались при возобновлении питания - то для этого существует соответствующая опция в BIOS. Погуглите.